# 3D model renders partially dark on ARToolKit

Tags: artoolkit, vrml, cinema-4d

I try to display a simple 3D model on ARToolKit but it renders partially dark for some reason.

If I display the model in a .wrl viewer like Cortona3D it looks perfect, so the problem must be ARToolKit. How can I fix this?

The model was made and exported to .wrl in Cinema 4D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by altering some values of the .wrl model with a text editor, the line was:

```
emissiveColor 0 0 0
```

I changed it to:

```
emissiveColor 1 1 1
```

For some reason ARToolKit gets confused with things like that.